# Why does a LINESTRING change in length after union with a shorter but completely-overlapping LINESTRING?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linestring, union

I have two linestrings that I am trying to merge and determine their total length:

[image: intersection of linestrings A and B]

This is a contrived example: the green linestring B is fully-contained within the red linestring A (but this will not always be the case), and the length of the merged geometry should be the same as the length of linestring A.

In PostGIS, if I calculate the length of the red linestring A with

> select st_length(st_geomfromtext('(A geom)'), false)

I get a result of 0.6102 (arbitrary units).

If I then calculate the length of the union of the red linestring A and green linestring B, via:

> select st_length(
>
> > st_union(
> >
> > > st_geomfromtext('(A geom)'),
> > >
> > > st_geomfromtext('(B geom)')
> >
> > ), false)

I then get a result of 0.6328, even though the green linestring B completely overlaps with the red linestring A.

I've tried many variations of merging these two linestrings involving st_unaryunion, st_linemerge, st_collect, st_dump, st_removerepeatedpoints and no luck.

How can I reconcile this? There are situations where the linestrings to be merged will not overlap 100% and I'll need to measure the length of the total union geometry, but I have trouble trusting that number when it seems to fail in this scenario.

For what it's worth, linestring A is:

> MULTILINESTRING((-84.3381536299124 33.7648637741265,-84.337082 33.76486,-84.3370269 33.7648551,-84.3367653 33.7648604,-84.336237 33.764861,-84.3358725 33.7648538,-84.335818 33.764857,-84.335192 33.764848,-84.3350945 33.7648474,-84.335009 33.764844,-84.334164 33.764846,-84.333928 33.764846,-84.3337994 33.7648477,-84.332997 33.764858,-84.332176 33.76486,-84.331834 33.764852,-84.330605 33.764845,-84.330119 33.764848,-84.329495 33.76486,-84.328663 33.764858,-84.327896 33.764867,-84.3275311259472 33.764859190368))

linestring B is:

> MULTILINESTRING((-84.3372103956974 33.7648604521912,-84.337082 33.76486,-84.3370269 33.7648551,-84.3367653 33.7648604,-84.3365005784092 33.7648607006492))

EDIT: an added wrinkle:
The length of linestring B is 0.04079. If I measure the intersection between both linestrings:

> select st_length(st_intersection(st_geomfromtext('(geom A')),st_geomfromtext('(geom B)'), false)

I get a result of 0.01821, which implies that there is (0.04079 - 0.01821) = 0.02258 of its length that doesn't overlap, which is the difference measured between st_length(A) and st_length(union(A,B)).

EDIT 2: this is getting weirder! I ran ST_SymDifference to find the area where these lines *didn't* intersect/overlap. It looks like this:
[image: Green dots are linestring B, black line is where B doesn't intersect with A]

So the point where the line doesn't cross the green dots is where both linestrings overlap, and that coincides to all of the points in linestring B that have identical matches in linestring A, which is every point except the first and last points of B.

So if I take the first point of linestring B (we'll call it P): POINT(-84.3372103956974 33.7648604521912) and see if it intersects with linestring A:

> select st_intersection(st_geomfromtext('(geom A)'), st_geomfromtext('POINT(-84.3372103956974 33.7648604521912)'))

I get "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY" as a result.

If I then try to find the point on A that is closest to P, it is ***identical*** to P:

> select st_astext(st_closestpoint(st_geomfromtext('(geom A)'), st_geomfromtext('POINT(-84.3372103956974 33.7648604521912)')))

The result is "POINT(-84.3372103956974 33.7648604521912)"!

On top of that, this also fails:

> select st_intersection(st_geomfromtext('(geom A)'), st_closestpoint(st_geomfromtext('(geom A)'), st_geomfromtext('POINT(-84.3372103956974 33.7648604521912)')))

The result is "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY", which seems quite broken since I'm requesting the intersection of a linestring with a point explicitly generated as being on that linestring. This query fails with the last point of B as well, but works with points 2, 3, and 4. The order of arguments (geom first, point second or vice versa) does not affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the query is as WKT

```
MULTILINESTRING (( -84.3381536299124 33.7648637741265, -84.337082 33.76486 ), ( -84.337082 33.76486, -84.3370269 33.7648551 ), ( -84.3370269 33.7648551, -84.3367653 33.7648604 ), ( -84.3367653 33.7648604, -84.336237 33.764861, -84.3358725 33.7648538, -84.335818 33.764857, -84.335192 33.764848, -84.3350945 33.7648474, -84.335009 33.764844, -84.334164 33.764846, -84.333928 33.764846, -84.3337994 33.7648477, -84.332997 33.764858, -84.332176 33.76486, -84.331834 33.764852, -84.330605 33.764845, -84.330119 33.764848, -84.329495 33.76486, -84.328663 33.764858, -84.327896 33.764867, -84.3275311259472 33.764859190368 ), ( -84.3372103956974 33.7648604521912, -84.337082 33.76486 ), ( -84.3367653 33.7648604, -84.3365005784092 33.7648607006492 ))
```

If you study that geometry with for example OpenJUMP you will see that the parts of the MultiLineString have an overlapping section at coordinates POINT (-84.3365005784092 33.7648607006492). Because of the duplicate part the length is longer. I believe that your linestring B is not totally fully contained by A if you look at every vertex.

Comment: I don't understand how that could be the case -- both linestring A and B were generated by ST_LineSubstring(), so they should both lie exactly on the same line, right? Separately, is there a way to merge two linestrings such that duplicate parts aren't counted twice?

Comment: Addind ST_SnapToGrid usually helps.

Comment: Lifesaver! For some reason having two points identical to 13 decimal places isn't enough to get them to overlap, but snapping to a grid of 0.00001 works. Might be mixing units there, but still: thanks a ton!